# Can't find where border is set in CSS

Tags: html, css

If you go to this page of the website ( http://portal.escalatehosting.com/clientarea.php ) and look at the border around the white content area, you'll see it's using this code:

```
#whmcscontent .whmcscontainer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    clear: both;
}
```

I want to add that same border around the white content area on this page as well:  http://www.escalatehosting.com/why-us.php

However, I can't seem to find in the CSS where exactly the code is that sets the border to know what needs to be changed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried it there but then the border was much thicker than the other.  Most likely because I don't know where the original one is set so that I can remove it and add this new one :/

Answer (score 1):

On the second page, you are actually seeing a `background-image` create the border.

It is being applied to the class `.s-inn-mid`.

```
.s-inn-mid {
    width: 976px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 12px 6px 12px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/middle.jpg) repeat-y;
}
```

To make both pages the same, simply remove the `background-image` and the float.

**Updated CSS class**

```
.s-inn-mid {
    width: 976px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 12px 6px 12px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```